# Change the color of specific characters of a PHP output

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have a php query which displays values after fetching data from database. The displayed values are like 'T', 'F' or 'R'. The echo command is working fine. I want to change the color of specific values when they are displayed in web page. For example- 'T' should be in green, 'F' should be in red and 'R' in yellow. How can I acheive that?

Thanks!

Following is a part of my code. Where should I insert the styling elements in the code?

```
$sql = "select * from <database table> where attribute1 = '$val1' and attribute2 = '$val2'";        
$fetch = $conn->query($sql);

if ($fetch->num_rows > 0) 
    {
         // output data of each row
     while($row = $fetch->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
           echo
              "<tr>
                  <td>".$row["col1"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["col2"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["col3"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["col4"]."</td>
                  <td>".$row["col5"]."</td>
               </tr>";
        }
     echo "</table>";
  } 
else  {
    echo "0 results";
  }
```

Comment: add the styling to the <td>

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with in-line styles, *however this is bad practice.*  Optimally, you'll want to apply classes to the output.

e.g.

```
<td class="green"></td>
<td class="red"></td>
<td class="yellow"></td>
```

Then within your CSS file, you'll have corresponding CSS classes.

```
.green{
  color: #0f0;
}
```

[Read more on the CSS property `color` on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)

Edit: adding part of my comment to the answer, based on OP's comment.

```
if($row['col1'] === 'T')
{
  $class = "green";
}
```

then when outputting the `<td></td>`s, loop:

```
echo "<td class='$class'></td>";
```

Alternatively:

```
echo '<td class="' . $class . '"></td>;
```

Comment: I don't think in-line styles will work here as $row["col1"] or $row["col2"] can fetch any one of the three values (T, F or R) depending on the values in database table.

Comment: Then you'll need to use a conditional to check what the output is, before `echo`ing it.

Comment: That's what I am looking for! But I am not able figure out how to do that. I am new to PHP and CSS stuff. I would appreciate if you can demonstrate where and how to use that conditional check in the code. Thanks!

Comment: e.g. `if ($row['col1'] === 'T') { $class = "green"; }` then later loop: `echo '<td class="' . $class . '"></td>';`  There's also a way to output the contents of a variable without having to concatenate strings, but I forget if it's single quotes or double quotes. The php would be something like: `echo "<td class='$class'></td>";`.  But again, I don't know if it's single quotes or double quotes.  Google would answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Create yourself a function that takes a value and outputs the `<td>` with the appropriate styling. I'm using inline styles here, but you can instead use CSS classes:

```
function color($value) {
    static $map = [ 'T' => 'green', 'F' => 'red', 'R' => 'yellow' ];
    return sprintf(
        '<td style="color:%s">%s</td>',
        array_key_exists($value, $map) ? $map[$value] : 'black',
        $value
    );
}
```

Now, instead of echoing the cell data directly, wrap it in a call to this function, like:

```
 while($row = $fetch->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
       echo
          "<tr>".
              color($row["col1"]).
              color($row["col2"]).
              color($row["col3"]).
              color($row["col4"]).
              color($row["col5"]).
           </tr>";
    }
```

Keeping the logic in a function lets you change the logic later without affecting the callers.

Answer (score 0):

If the `col1` in the database table has these single values `T`, `F` and `R` on each rows respectively, consider the following code:

```
<?php

    $color_codes = array(
        'T' => 'green',
        'F' => 'red',
        'R' => 'yellow'
    );

    $sql = "select * from <database table> where attribute1 = '$val1' and attribute2 = '$val2'";        
    $fetch = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($fetch->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $fetch->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td style='color: " . $color_codes[$row['col1']] . "'>" . $row["col1"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["col2"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["col3"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["col4"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["col5"] . "</td>
                </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

?>
```

**OR**

```
<style>
    .red {
        color: red;
    }

    .green {
        color: green;
    }

    .yellow {
        color: yellow;
    }
</style>

<?php

    $color_codes = array(
        'T' => 'green',
        'F' => 'red',
        'R' => 'yellow'
    );

    $sql = "select * from <database table> where attribute1 = '$val1' and attribute2 = '$val2'";        
    $fetch = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($fetch->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $fetch->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td class='" . $color_codes[$row['col1']] . "'>" . $row["col1"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["col2"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["col3"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["col4"] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["col5"] . "</td>
                </tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

?>
```

The only difference in the second code is the `class` attribute is added and `style` attribute is removed to define CSS rules for each color in the stylesheet. Both code works.

You can stick with the code that you're comfortable with. But the first one is flexible because you don't need to add CSS rules in the stylesheet for each color.

Hope it helps!